# Assert cuando no se pudo crear un objeto en Django

Tags: django

Estoy realizando las pruebas de la creación de un objeto y quisiera saber cómo hacer la prueba para hacer un assert en caso de que no se pudiera crear el objeto.
Por ejemplo:

```
   def test_expediente_sin_nombre(self):
    try:
        Expediente.objects.create(
            apellido_paterno='Prueba 2',
            apellido_materno='Prueba 1',
            estado_nacimiento='Oaxaca',
            fecha_nacimiento='2000-01-01'
        )
        self.fail("No se pudo crear")
    except FooException:
        pass
    expediente_counts = Expediente.objects.filter(apellido_paterno='Prueba 2').count()
    self.assertRaises(FooException)
```

En este caso el expediente no se debería crear el expediente porque falta el nombre, si no se crea entonces la prueba pasó.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo tienes dos alternativas.

En producción, deberías capturar ese error al *limpiar* los datos de un formulario, veamos el ejemplo de [la documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute):

```
from django import forms

class ExpedienteForm(forms.Form):
    # ...

    def clean_nombre(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['nombre']
        if "Esteban" not in data:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Falta el nombre!")
        return data
```

O bien, deberías indicar que el campo es obligatorio y validar en el modelo usando `Model.clean()`, como indica la [misma documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean):

```
class Expediente(models.Model):
    ...
    def clean(self):
        if self.nombre == None:
            raise ValidationError({'nombre': 'El nombre es obligatorio'})
```

Y en las pruebas, verificar que se lance este error:

```
def test_expediente_sin_nombre(self):
    expediente = Expediente.objects.create(
        apellido_paterno='Prueba 2',
        apellido_materno='Prueba 1',
        estado_nacimiento='Oaxaca',
        fecha_nacimiento='2000-01-01'
    )
    self.assertRaises(ValidationError, Expediente.clean)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, sí pude solucionarlo de ese modo.